# Question about Mod Elections

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

So what is the difference between the moderator role, and the moderator privileges given to members with 10k+ rep points?

I ask because it may impact how I vote in the elections.  I think Anders has been a fantastic Mod, but since he has over 10k rep points I think he has the same privileges and certainly he holds the same klout with me.

Aside from the small diamond next to the name, what is the difference?  There are a couple of us that will be approaching the 10k level so this I figured I would ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a very large difference between a 10k user and a diamond moderator in the available moderator abilities. The FAQ is a bit misleading in that regard.

[From a post on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role/75192#75192)

> Diamond moderators are human exception handlers.  The main function of
>   [diamond
>   moderators](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)
>   is to follow up on [flagged
>   posts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/) but
>   they also have some special abilities necessary to handle rare
>   exceptional conditions:
>
> - They have access to all the abilities of 10k users regardless of their reputation.
> - Their votes are binding. Any place we have voting — close, open, delete, undelete, offensive, migration, etc — that vote will reach the
>     threshold and take effect immediately if a single diamond moderator
>     casts a vote.
> - They can [lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)
>     posts. Locked posts cannot be voted on, commented, or changed in any
>     way.
> - They can [protect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question/)
>     questions. Protected questions only allow answers by users with more
>     than 10 reputation.
> - They can see more data in the system, including vote statistics (but not ‘who voted for this post’) and user profile information.
> - They can view all deleted posts on an individual user's profile.
> - They can place users in timed suspension, and delete users if necessary.
> - They can perform large-scale maintenance actions such as merging questions and tags, tag synonym approvals, unbounded question
>     migration, and so forth.
> - They can convert a post into Community Wiki status, or convert an answer into a comment.

Comment: extremely helpful, thanks!

Comment: we can also use the mod tools to detect suspicious vote patterns, dig in IP logs etc to detect if people are using sockpuppet voting etc.

Comment: what is sockpuppet voting?

Comment: Its when you create fake accounts you use to upvote your own answers, or even ask questions you then can answer (yes, people actually do that) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockpuppet_(Internet)

Comment: @AndersRask "Astroturfing" is another amusingly named form of abuse you can see with such tools, I believe.

Comment: @AndersRask that is just sad....